# What's the use of pos+=1 here?

Tags: javascript, html, css

CSS:

```
 <style>
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;

}
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
</style>
<div id="container">
   <div id="box"> </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var pos = 0; 
var box = document.getElementById("box");
function move() {
  pos += 1;
  box.style.left = pos+"px"
}
```

If I just use `box.style.left = "150px"` the red box will be right in the corner of the green box but if I use `box.style.left = pos+"50px"` the same happens and I don't know why? I don't understand why even declare the variable pos in the first place.

Comment: What uses the move function?  I'm guessing this is something that moves the element 1 pixel at a time.  This is a good example of why putting comments in your code is necessary.

Comment: Is that all the JS code you have? It would seem that `move()` is to move the box across the screen over time.

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QYzEEp, pos is used to move the box from left to right by px specified in pos + 1

Answer (score 0):

That is shorthand for `pos = pos +1;`

It's then being used to style the div with the id of box 1 pixel to the right, based on the left margin, so it will nudge right across page.

You'd need some sort of click handler associated to a button in the HTML markup to call move to make something happen.

Answer (score 0):

pos + '50px' is 150px , as number plus string , will be concatenated string as mentioned below

```
pos = 0

pos += 1 //pos = 0 + 1 = 1

pos = 1 + '50px' // 150px ,as string it concatenates to 150px
```

codepen = https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QYzEEp